# AngularJS animate image on src change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an AnuglarJS app, where I load/change some images from a webservice...

Controller

```
.controller('PlayerCtrl', function($scope, programService) {
    ....
    programService.refresh(function(data) {
        $scope.program = data;
    });
    ....
```

Template

```
<img src="{{program.image}}" />
```

When my app updates from the webservice the images changes as expected, I just want to make an fadeout / fadein when this happens, how can that be done?

Is it possible to always make a fadeout/in when a image src changes?

Comment: I suggest combinating ngAnimate and a watch on the src model. Just don't have the time to work it out right now.

Comment: You should be using `ng-src` for images with dynamic sources.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks for the responses -

I ended up doing this, and it works ;)

--- Directive ---

```
.directive('fadeIn', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
            $element.addClass("ng-hide-remove");
            $element.on('load', function() {
                $element.addClass("ng-hide-add");
            });
        }
    };
})
```

--- Template ---

```
<img ng-src="{{program.image}}" class="animate-show" fade-in />
```

--- CSS ---

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    display: block !important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for sharing! Is there any chance that somebody would know if this animation could be staggered? I tried adding 
`.circle-image.ng-hide-stagger{
 transition-delay: 0.1s;

 transition-duration: 0s;
}` amongst others, to no avail.

Comment: you just update the $scope.program.image ? I just tried doing the same thing, but the first image is fade-in, the images after that - are just cut over ( no animation )

Comment: my mistake, in Ionic's framework I needed to add a class "animated" so that the DOM can be animated using ngAnimate

Comment: @Ricky Where di you add your animated class? I'm trying the same thing `onClick`but my images are just switching over with no animation.

Comment: @AgentZebra `class="animated <animation-you-want>" ng-show="some expression"` see: http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/

Answer (score 11):

**Update 1.5.x -** with Angular 1.5.x you can use [ngAnimateSwap](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/docs/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateSwap) to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

As [christoph has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719408/angularjs-animate-image-on-src-change/25725287#comment-40206975), you should watch using `$watch` on the image source change. 
But first make sure you use the `ng-src` rather than the `src` for the `image` tag.

```
<image id="new" ng-src="program.image" />

$scope.$watch('program.image', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue===oldValue) return;
    $('img#new').hide();
    $('img#new').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
})
```

Comment: What do you name the animation css in this case?

Comment: @AgentZebra I did not consider the use of css here. You can use use Jquery's .hide() and .fadeIn to achieve the effect. The fadeout effect might not be possible. I suggest using the directive as proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25725287/1690339

Answer (score 0):

Based on pkdkk's answer and the Angular.js 1.3.6 sources, my solution is as such (the CSS animation part is as used for standard `ngShow`):

```
// Copied from the Angular's sources.
var NG_HIDE_CLASS = 'ng-hide';
var NG_HIDE_IN_PROGRESS_CLASS = 'ng-hide-animate';

app.directive('myFadeIn', function($animate, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.addClass("ng-hide");
            element.on('load', function() {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $animate.removeClass(element, NG_HIDE_CLASS, {
                        tempClasses: NG_HIDE_IN_PROGRESS_CLASS
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case others end up here wanting to perform animations on change of a background image, I'll post what I ended up using.

This directive assumes it's attached to a template like this:

```
<!-- Full screen background image and scarecrow for onload event-->
<div class="full-screen-image" data-background-image="{{backgroundImageUrl}}"></div>
<img class="hidden-full-screen-image hidden" data-ng-src="{{backgroundImageUrl}}"></div>
```

We want to set the background image source for the `<div>`, but attach an onload event so we know when the new image has arrived. To do that, we use an `<img>` with a `.hidden` class that has `.hidden {display: none;}`. Then we use the following directive to dynamically set the div's background image source and perform a fade to white then back from white on image change:

```
/***
*
* Directive to dynamically set background images when 
* controllers update their backgroundImageUrl scope
* variables
*
* Template: <div data-background-image="{{backgroundImageUrl}}" />
*   AND     <img data-background-image="{{backgroundImageUrl}}" class="image-onload-target hidden" />
*
***/

var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('BackgroundImage', [])
  .directive('backgroundImage', [
    "$timeout",
  function ($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    attrs.$observe('backgroundImage', function(value) {

      /***
      *
      * Define a callback to trigger once the image loads.
      * The value provided to this callback = the value
      * passed to attrs.$observe() above
      *
      ***/

      var imageLoadedCallback = function(value) {
        // once the image load event triggers, remove the event
        // listener to ensure the event is called only once
        fadeOut();
        target.removeEventListener('load', imageLoadedCallback);
        $timeout(function() {
          fadeIn(value);
        }, 700);
      }

      /***
      *
      * Define fade in / out events to be called once a new image
      * is passed to the attrs.backgroundImage in the directive
      *
      ***/

      var fadeOut = function() {
        element.css({'opacity': '0'})
      };

      var fadeIn = function(value) {
        element.css({
          'background': 'url(' + value +') no-repeat center center fixed',
          'background-size' : 'cover',
          'opacity': '1'
        });
      };

      // add an onload event to the hidden-full-screen-image
      var target = document.querySelector('.image-onload-target');
      target.addEventListener('load', imageLoadedCallback(value));

    });
  };
}]);
```

Working with Angular makes me love React all the more...

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but according to @Aides answer i am posting here an working example that how can you achieve animation with change in `ng-src` using `ngAnimateSwap` (with Angular 1.5.x). I hope this helps someone in future:

HTML Markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngAnimateSwap-directive-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngAnimateSwapExample" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <img ng-animate-swap="activeImage" class="cell swap-animation" ng-src="{{activeImage}}" alt="My Active Image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Current Image: {{activeImage}}
    <br />
    <button ng-click="previous()">Previous</button>
    <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS `(script.js)`:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ngAnimateSwapExample', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

      var baseUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports";
      $scope.images = [];
      $scope.startIndex = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.images.push(baseUrl + "/" + i);
      }

      $scope.activeImage = $scope.images[$scope.startIndex];
      /*
            $interval(function() {
              $scope.startIndex++;
              if($scope.images[$scope.startIndex] && $scope.images[$scope.startIndex] != undefined){
                  $scope.activeImage = $scope.images[$scope.startIndex];  
              }

            }, 2000);
        */
      $scope.previous = function() {

        $scope.startIndex--;
        $timeout(function() {
          if ($scope.images[$scope.startIndex] && $scope.images[$scope.startIndex] !== undefined) {
            $scope.activeImage = $scope.images[$scope.startIndex];
          }
        }, 500);

      };

      $scope.next = function() {
        $scope.startIndex++;
        $timeout(function() {
          if ($scope.images[$scope.startIndex] && $scope.images[$scope.startIndex] !== undefined) {
            $scope.activeImage = $scope.images[$scope.startIndex];
          }
        }, 500);
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fzs2DfOpOqRCeDwgnmdy?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to watch for changes on ng-src and using a timeout function to add a class which does the fadeIn effect.

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="your-logic-will-go-here" class="animate-show ng-hide-add" fade-in>
```

**Angular Code**

```
.directive('fadeIn', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
            $scope.$watch('selectedFormat.name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue!=oldValue) {
                    $element.removeClass("ng-hide-add");
                    $element.addClass("ng-hide-remove");
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $element.addClass("ng-hide-add");
                    }, 100);
                }
            })
        }
    };
})
```

**CSS**

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide-add{
      transition: all linear 0.7s;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't animate an `img src` change. You can, however, have multiple images and animate their opacity.

#### HTML/angular template

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="image-one.jpg" ng-show="showImageOne">
    <img src="image-two.jpg" ng-show="showImageTwo">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s opacity linear;
}

.image-container img.ng-hide {
    display: block!important;
    opacity: 0;
}
```