# Angular ng-src change animation

Tags: angularjs, animation

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719408/angularjs-animate-image-on-src-change) to find out how to animate the change of `ng-src`. This doesn't seem to work however, only the first time when loading the page.

I want to create an animation when the `ng-src` of an image changes, and came up with the following directive:

```
myApp.directive("imageChange", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("load", function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.removeClass("ng-hide");
                    element.addClass("ng-show");
                }, 500); // This also is shitty, cause its a fixed value
            });
            attrs.$observe("ngSrc", function () {
                element.removeClass("ng-show");
                element.addClass("ng-hide");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to animate. What should be the correct solution to animate the `ng-src` change?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wszk0tr1/3/

Answer (score 5):

With one image it was fading but on top of white background. I was able to fade it on top of previous image with two images.

It works by showing the prev image  and fading the new image

```
&.ng-hide-fade{
    opacity: 0;
   transition: 0s all linear;
  -webkit-transition: 0s all linear;
}

&.ng-show{
    opacity: 1;
   transition: 1s all linear;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all linear;
}
```

working fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/bysdntox/gnf384gb/

Comment: Man, you saved two more days of my investigation.This must be the perfect answer.

Comment: @sudhir Awesome answer! You're a genius!