# Animate image on changing through dropdown selector angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="loaded"/>
<select ng-model="list">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.name}}">{{option.id}}</option>
</select>
{{list}}
<button ng-click="addtext()">Button</button>
<div id="container">
  <img id="profile" ng-src="{{list}}" ng-show="loaded"/>
</div>
```

This is my html. i want to animate the image appearance (fade out old image and fade in new image) when i select image from the dropdown list. how to acheive this in angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS animate image on src change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719408/angularjs-animate-image-on-src-change)

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of using ng-model, use ng-change, and point to a function in the controller scope. For example (the example uses jQuery):

```
<select ng-change="changePic()">

---------

$scope.changePic = function() {
    $('img#profile').fadeOut(500,
        function() {
            $scope.list = $('select').val();
            $('img#profile').fadeIn(500);
        }
    );
}
```

I didn't test this, may not work.